# Can the Flash run backwards?

Tags: dc, the-flash

When we see him run, if he overshoots, we see him just run around the world again.  However, has there been any moments where we see him run backwards? Is he able to maintain the same speeds that he does when he runs forward?

Comment: ...Wouldn't simply turning around and going back be faster than going all the way around the world?  Even for the Flash that just seems like a waste of effort.

Comment: If he can run around the world in less than 90 minutes, then he'll be running at greater than orbital velocity. How can he "run" if he can't touch the ground? Also, even if it takes him 90 minutes to go all the way around the world, he would be running at more than twenty times the speed of sound. He would need Super Strength, to do that, and he also would need to be Super Fire-proof.

Comment: @SolomonSlow: Like many superheroes, the Flash has a lot of [required secondary powers](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RequiredSecondaryPowers). You'll break your brain if you try to work out all the implications of making his primary power not be suicidal in one way or another.

Comment: @SolomonSlow you forget the crucial part of any flash answer: Speed Force

Comment: @SolomonSlow: It's canon! (elapsed time ~10 sec) https://youtu.be/R8cmHXwKfLY?t=92

Comment: @DanielR.Collins sigh... what an awesome show

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I can only reinforce [Laurel's offering](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/232854/58193).

The panels below are taken from *Brave & Bold* #67 (1966), with a recuperating Flash showing the villain what speed is really all about!

[image: The Flash catches up to the villain then turns around as he passes him to run backwards, the villain remarks: He--He's passing me... going backwards! I must be dreaming!]

Answer (score 20):

He does in the comics:

[image: Running backwards vs Quicksilver]

(Presumably, it’s the same as anyone else running backwards: it’s not as fast as running forwards, but it’s much more showy.)

I believe this image is from the [JLA/Avengers](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/JLA/Avengers) crossover.

(Related: In [another story](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/The_Flash_Vol_1_107) the Flash is outsped by some other guy running backwards.)

Comment: It is for a fact from the Avengers/JLA crossover epic.

Comment: Is he actually running backwards here, or coming to a halt while turning around?

Comment: @Mast Probably the latter; if he came to a halt over water he'd sink in and then have to somehow get out of/above the water again (not impossible but probably something he wants to avoid).

Answer (score 15):

Not only can he run backwards, he can still outrun Superman while doing so. We see this in the race scene from *Smallville*.